# TeXLive 2011 - Windows XP installation

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

I've been searching for installation files for TL **2011** and been reading people using it but on the official site I can only download tl-manager for 2010. Can someone post the resources/links, please?

Comment: It is not released just yet, although the pre-test is available. As this is very much a passing issue, I wonder if the question is 'too localised'. I'd expect release to happen in one to two weeks, based on discussion on the TL list.

Comment: On http://tug.org/texlive it says "1jul11: deliver final images for the TeX Collection DVD.", so it seems to be really close to the release.

Comment: @panny: Could you accept egreg's answer so that the question is concluded. Thank you!

Comment: @Martin: Since this question isn't really relevant anymore, I'd close as 'too localized'.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close the topic and inform @panny, TeX Live 2011 is available

http://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html